# simple_form and hstore basic functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, hstore

I can get hstore to work with simple_form but all but the most basic functionality (saving) just doesn't work.  Validation messages don't show up on the individual fields... all hstore fields oddly show as required, even the values themselves don't populate correctly unless set manually.

I have to do something like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :phones do |phone| %>
    <%= phone.input :agent, :input_html => { :value => @artist.phones['agent'] } %>
<% end %>
```

I have to use simple_fields_for for the hstore hash and it saves properly but on edit the values don't populate without using the input_html to set the value.  It marks every field as required and validation errors don't show up at all (they do work).

Using hstore validations like so (added from below answer):

```
validates_hstore :emails do
  validates_format_of [:agent,:artist], :with => /@/, :allow_blank => true
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of how to add some custom validations for Hstore here:

https://gist.github.com/rf-/2322543

```
module HstoreValidation
  def validates_hstore(field, &block)
    validation_class = Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations

      def self.name
        '(validations)'
      end

      def initialize(data)
        @data = data
      end

      def read_attribute_for_validation(attr_name)
        @data[attr_name]
      end
    end
    validation_class.class_eval &block

    validate do
      validator = validation_class.new(self[field])

      if validator.invalid?
        validator.errors.each do |attr, text|
          self.errors.add(attr, text)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But as for how to get the validations to work with Simple form, I'm not sure.