# rails 4.1 validation of arbitrary fields via hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I use HStore in Rails 4.1 to manage I18n and storage of languages.  It works great the only problem I have is I would like to do something like this (instead of using store_accessor)

In Rails 4.0 this worked great:

https://gist.github.com/rf-/2322543 ([simple_form and hstore basic functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523112/simple-form-and-hstore-basic-functionality/17731272?noredirect=1#comment39694138_17731272))

So I could simple do something like:

```
  validates_hstore :content do
    validates_presence_of :en
  end
```

Where the magic happened (doesn't seem to work correctly in Rails 4.1)

```
module HstoreValidation
  def validates_hstore(field, &block)
    validation_class = Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations

      def self.name
        '(validations)'
      end

      def initialize(data)
        @data = data
      end

      def read_attribute_for_validation(attr_name)
        @data[attr_name]
      end
    end
    validation_class.class_eval &block

    validate do
      validator = validation_class.new(self[field])

      if validator.invalid?
        validator.errors.each do |attr, text|
          self.errors.add(attr, text)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Instead i always get, even when the field is not blank:

```
messages:
  :en:
  - can't be blank
```

Comment: sidenote: current syntax for validatons:  validates :en, presence: { presence: true, message: "Custom message" },

Comment: Can you please add how this module needs to be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it happens because hstore key/values are converted to strings, and when validation tries to validate attribute `:en` it always will be `nil`, so you could replace your `read_attribute_for_validation` method to:

```
def read_attribute_for_validation(attr_name)
  @data[attr_name.to_s]
end
```

note: `attr_name.to_s`

---

also you could use `store_accessor` like:

```
store_accessor :content, :en

validates :en, presence: true
```